# Building Subquery to be a column/Field Name

Tags: sql, teradata

I am unable to bundled groups of subqueries correctly in order to create column titled "Discharge_To"

I am using Teradata Studio Express. I was asked to create a column for field that is not inside a table we normally used. We want to know where a patient was discharged to from a previous place of service. In order to answer this, there has to be steps to determine that. So far, I can get it read correctly until line 94.

```sql
Select S.Member_ID, S.PAC_Sty_ID, S.Stay_Admit_Date, S.Stay_Discharge_Date, S.POS, S.LOS,
  (
    Select
      S.Member_ID, S.PAC_Sty_ID,
      Case
        When S.Discharge_To is null 
          and H.POS is not null And S.POS <> '12' then 'Home With Care'
        When S.Discharge_To is null then 'Home Without Care'
        Else S.Discharge_To 
      End Discharge_To
    From (
      Select
        S.Member_ID, S.PAC_Sty_ID, S.Stay_Admit_Date, S.Stay_Discharge_Date, S.POS,
        Case trim(D.POS)
          When '21' then 'Hospital' When '23' then 'ER' When '31' then 'SNF'
          When '61' then 'IRF' When 'LTAC' then 'LTAC'
        End Discharge_To
      From ECONIMICS.PAC_02_MODEL_SUMMARY_Combined S
      Left Join (
        Select S.Member_ID, S.PAC_Sty_ID, S.POS, S.Stay_Admit_Date, S.Stay_Discharge_Date
        From ECONIMICS.PAC_02_MODEL_SUMMARY_Combined S
        Where PAC_Sty_ID is not null
        And POS <> '12'
      ) D On D.Member_ID = S.Member_ID And D.PAC_Sty_ID <> S.PAC_Sty_ID
        And D.Stay_Admit_Date Between S.Stay_Admit_Date and S.Stay_Discharge_Date + 1
      Where S.PAC_Sty_ID is not null
      Qualify Row_Number() Over (
        Partition By S.PAC_Sty_ID Order By Case trim(D.POS) 
          When '21' then 1 When 'LTAC' then 2 when '61' then 3 When '31' then 4 end
      ) = 1
    ) S
    Left Join (
      Select *
      From ECONIMICS.PAC_02_MODEL_SUMMARY_Combined
      Where POS = '12'
    ) H On H.Member_ID = S.Member_ID
      And H.From_Date Between S.Stay_Discharge_Date and S.Stay_Discharge_Date + 7
    Qualify Row_Number() Over (Partition By S.PAC_Sty_ID Order By H.From_Date) = 1
) E On E.Member_ID = S.Member_ID And E.PAC_Sty_ID = S.PAC_Sty_ID
Where S.PAC_Sty_ID is not Null
AND S.STAY_DISCHARGE_DATE between '2017-01-01' and '2020-12-31'
AND S.LOB in ('CARE', 'DUAL')
AND S.ORPHAN_CLM_ID IS NULL
AND S.ORPHAN_CLM_LN IS NULL
Group By 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

There should be 7 columns with the 7th column titled "Discharge_to" and values in the seventh column would be text (e.g., "Home without Care")

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: The error is on line 94 on the "On" where it was expecting any of the following: "Except, Expand, For, From, Group, Having, etc."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting here, since it's easier.  Your query doesn't seem to be formatted correctly.  It's of this form:

```sql
select S.Member_ID, ... , 
  (
    Select ... -- Sub-query trying to derive Discharge_To field
  ) E on E.Member_ID = S.Member_ID ...
where ...
```

A couple notes:

- There is no `FROM` clause in the outer query yet you are trying to return `S.` fields
- There is no `S` result set to join your `E` result to
- The `E` result set is trying to be used as a sub-SELECT, but it also has an alias

Not knowing what your error message is, I'd suggest breaking apart the query into its sub-queries and running those individually to try to determine where the problem lies.

Comment: Thank you, Ravioli. This whole query was actually part of a "Merge Into/Using"  and "When Matched Then Update Set" subquery to normalize new data. Without going too deep in what I am doing, our data team provides the fields we need in one client's data, but not in the other. Because they do not plan to make both client's data the same (we connect queries to Tableau), I have to figure out how to create the missing fields. I found the scrub query and was hoping to mimic the part that creates the "Discharge_To" field. The error is "Encountered "On" was expecting, " Except, From, etc...."

Comment: Hmm...OK.  the query you posted won't run as-is because of syntax errors near the `ON` clause.  Do you have the exact working query from the `MERGE INTO` request?  I'm assuming the sub-query you pasted is the `USING` sub-query of the `MERGE`.  If so, it should run by itself as a stand-alone query.

Comment: Yes, I have the Merge Into query and it runs fine. I was hoping to convert it to a query just to build the "Discharge_To" column by changing it from "Using" sub-query to a stand alone query. Let me try running it without and modifications.

Comment: Does not work. REmoved the Merge Into line and got the error on "Using" and when I removed "Using" the error jumped to end of group on "E"

Comment: The way `MERGE INTO` works, is it merges data from a source table (or query which seems to be your case) into a target table.  The `WHEN MATCHED/NOT MATCHED` controls what to do for matching / unmatched rows.  I'm guessing your entire query is structured something like this:  `MERGE INTO tgt USING (select ...) src ON tgt.pk_col = src.pk_col WHEN MATCHED THEN ... WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN ...`.  If you try running only the `sub_query` inside the `USING ( <sub_query> )` part, do you get the same errors?

Comment: OK. Took the whole subquery and made it into a Left Join and aliased it as "Discharge_To" and it ran with no errors. However, I got only Nulls and there should have been values. I will tweak it from there, but I deeply thank you for your tips...it helped me greatly.

Comment: Added Client ID in the where's and now I get values. Thank you again!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working :)  If you get stuck anywhere else, just post again on here and we'll help you out.